# Placing several atlas' features into a single page

Tags: qgis, atlas

All the documentations and tutorials I've been reading about QGIS' Atlas are focused on creating an atlas in which every page is a feature. Or in other words: where every feature is placed in its own single page.

I am wondering if it could be possible to create an atlas in which all their features were placed within the same page, in order to accomplish something like this:

[image: Image source from this magnificient R tutorial: https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/blob/master/README.md]

This image has been taken from [this magnificent R tutorial](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/) and displays population evolution in an array of maps within the same page. I thought that could be achieved in QGIS by creating an atlas where each year is a different feature, but Atlas' default behaviour would place each year in a different page, which is not exactly what I want, as I am sacrificing the power of seeing an evolution in just an image.

Any clues on that?

Comment: Do u mean with an automatic generation and placement of every frame (and a variable amount of frames) ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but let me explain mine better: I would like to reproduce the attached image with QGIS, where each year is a feature but instead of being placed in different pages, they are all placed in the same one.

Comment: I don't think Atlas will be able to iterate through each time period and update the same image. Could you use the Atlas to generate all the separate images and then combine them into one using your favourite image editor (like GIMP). Or create your page layout with a map frame for each image and then style the data for each frame and lock it afterwards. Then export.

Comment: @mixedbredie I was writing a suggestion for the second part of your comment to resize the frame in the layout view and locking layer items and styles.

Comment: @ahmadhanb I'd be interested to see your solution. Python or data defined?

Comment: @mixedbredie. Thanks for your comment. Let me explain it further: I didn't mean to update a single image, but to create a series of images (being each image a feature) within a same page. I know I could generate an atlas in which each feature is a different image and then combine them using an image editor, but that's exactly what I wanted to avoid, as it is not trivial to create an array and it is quite time consuming and prone-error.

Comment: Is it your goal to have multiple map windows in one compostion, every map window seperatly showing another atlas feature at the same time? AFAIK this is not possible at the moment because of how the atlas is working. The composer can manage just one atlas at a time and processes only the 'active' atlas feature. We will see what the big composer upgrade of QGIS 3.0 will change. There are possible solutions to your task but not with multiple map windows in QGIS < 3.0

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, I found this QGIS' plugin that does actually that: https://github.com/Korto19/Multiple-Maps

This is an example:

[image]